# Right click in windows on a SVN folder shared in wsl takes forever.... WHY?

Tags: windows, svn, tortoisesvn, wsl-2

We have svn repos checked out on our windows machines, and using WSL to compile the code.
When we then in windows right click on the folder to get the right click context menu, it takes +20sec for the context menu to be displayed...

Does anyone have a clue on what is going on and why?
and maybe even have a fix???

\Kenni

Answer (score 1):

If you have Tortoise SVN installed it's likely the culprit.

I solved the problem by setting "settings", "general", "Context Menu", "Do not show the context menu for the following paths" to `\\wsl.localhost\*`